# What's wrong with this macro?

Tags: c, macros

I am facing a problem with a macro and I can't figure out why.

Here is the macro :

```
#define WAIT(condition, max_time)               \
   do {                                         \
      int int_loop_wait=0;                      \
      while(1)                                  \    
      {                                         \           
        if(condition) { break; }                \
        sleep(1);                               \
        if(int_loop_wait>=max_time) { break; }  \
        int_loop_wait++;                        \
      }                                         \
    } while(0)                                  \
```

I got the error

> "expected a declaration" line   " if(condition) { break; } "

Does anyone understand this error?

Comment: You are not changing `int_loop_wait` inside the loop. `max_time` has no effect.

Comment: True ! I change it right now . I keep you update

Comment: @ Krishnabhadra 

It's a macro, so I don't want the semi colon (it will be added in the code)

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, no need for the `;` if you wan to write `WAIT(condition, max_time);` somewhere in the code

Comment: Where is the macro invocation?

Comment: @Dipto You were right it was a none-sense but I still get the error.

Comment: my code::block ide formats macros in green. from the line `if(condition) { break; }` its formatting like other code. not sure about the reason.. :(

Comment: @Dipto Probably the same error as I get... It has to have a reason ! ;)

Comment: if the bracket start in the same line its solved. but not sure about the reason.

Comment: Ouch! I opened the preprocessed file (.i in Visual C++) and there's just no code above `if(condition)`.

Comment: @Joze Ya. correct.. forgot the macro thing..

Comment: Interesting. If I remove the whitespaces after backslashes the macro is processed okay - no error.

Comment: @Jose: There're whitespaces on the right of some backslash characters.

Comment: Ya.. white space is the culprit

Comment: ANy chance you can paste your code in answer (in order to try)?

Comment: its working fine in ma sys :) in gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: i have tried same; and its workin..try gcc -E file.c

Comment: @Joze remove all spaces after the `\\`. my answer is updated

Comment: @sharptooth is definitely right ! I tried and it's working. Please create an answer about it to get the checkmark.

Comment: @Joze: I won't because I have no idea why it behaves this way.

Comment: @sharptooth its because macro definition continues to next line if the line ends with \ only. The definition was ended just after the white space and not continued to next line.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that the backslash followed by a whitespace are together recognized as an escape sequence which in effect cancels out the backslash. Visual C++ 10 even emits `error C2017: illegal escape sequence` there.

Some of the lines in the code snippet (for example the one with `while(1)`) contain one or more whitespaces after backslash. Once the backslashes are treated as escape sequences and removed by the compiler the macro definition gets truncated at that line and the remaining code is compiled as if it doesn't belong to the macro definition.

```
#define WAIT(condition, max_time)               \
   do {                                         \
      int int_loop_wait=0;                      \
      while(1)                                  \    <<<<<WHITESPACES
      {                                         \<<<this line doesn't belong to macro
        if(condition) { break; }                \<<<and neither does this 
        sleep(1);                               \
        if(int_loop_wait>=max_time) { break; }  \
        int_loop_wait++;                        \
      }                                         \
    } while(0)                                  \
```

Comment: What a life saver! Thanks. Be careful and check for those unwanted key pressed when writing long macro

Answer (score 9):

remove the `\` from the last line

I mean change this line

```
 } while(0)                                                     \
```

by

```
 } while(0)
```

And remove all spaces after the `\`

you have some lines which contain spaces after the `\` like:

```
while(1)                                  \    
      {                                         \
```

Comment: Any idea why spaces cause the problem?

Comment: white spaces will get u some wornings thats it..like c.c:4:49: warning: backslash and newline separated by space [enabled by default]
c.c:5:49: warning: backslash and newline separated by space [enabled by default]

Answer (score 6):

The culprit is white space after `\`. Removing them will solve.

Macro definition continues if the line ends with `\`, but not with space  or any other character.

```
#define WAIT(condition, max_time)                                  \
   do {                                                            \
      int int_loop_wait=0;                                         \
      while(1){                                                    \
        if(condition) { break; }                                   \
        sleep(1);                                                  \
    if(int_loop_wait>=max_time) { break; }                         \
      }                                                            \
    } while(0)
```